# Why doesn't Metal render my simple clear window code?

Tags: xcode, gpu, metal, metalkit

I have been following [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/devices_and_commands) tutorial. I downloaded the source and tried "translating" it to Swift. This is my "translated" code:

```
import Cocoa
import AppKit
import MetalKit

import simd


class MetalViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet var inview: MTKView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let _view: MTKView = self.inview
        _view.device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
        let _renderer: Renderer=initView(view: _view)
        _view.delegate=_renderer as? MTKViewDelegate
        _view.preferredFramesPerSecond=60
    }
}
class Renderer: NSObject {
    init(device: MTLDevice){
        self._device=device
        self._commandQueue=_device.makeCommandQueue()!
        super.init()
    }
    func mtkView(_ view: MTKView, drawableSizeWillChange size: CGSize) {

    }
    func draw(in view: MTKView) {
        let color = Color(red: 1.0,green: 0.0,blue: 0.0,alpha: 0.0)
        view.clearColor = MTLClearColorMake(color.red, color.green, color.blue, color.alpha)
        let commandbuffer = _commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer()
        let renderpassdescriptor: MTLRenderPassDescriptor = view.currentRenderPassDescriptor!
        let renderencoder: MTLRenderCommandEncoder = (commandbuffer?.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: renderpassdescriptor))!
        renderencoder.endEncoding()
        commandbuffer!.present(view.currentDrawable!)
        commandbuffer!.commit()
    }

    var _device: MTLDevice
    var _commandQueue: MTLCommandQueue

}

struct Color{
    var red, green, blue, alpha: Double
}

func initView(view: MTKView) -> Renderer{
    var renderer: Renderer
    renderer=Renderer(device: view.device!)
    return renderer
}
```

So I put the AAPLRenderer and AAPLViewControllers into one file, and made it so that there are no header files. I linked the view with @IBOutlet to the view controller because the view was a NSView and I cannot cast it to MTKView without getting a compile time error. The AppDelegate is the original one and I do not have a main file.

I end up with a window that does not show red, but rather shows nothing. I do not understand why this is happening. Please help me, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues.

1) `MTKView`'s `delegate` property is a `weak var`, which means that if you don't hold onto an instance of your renderer, it'll be immediately deinited and never receive any delegate callbacks. Keep a reference to your renderer as a property on your view controller.

```
class MetalViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet var inview: MTKView!
    var renderer: Renderer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // ...
        let view: MTKView = self.inview
        // ...
        renderer = initView(view: view)
        view.delegate = renderer
        // ...
    }
}
```

2) Because the `Renderer` class doesn't explicitly declare conformance to the `MTKViewDelegate` protocol, the conditional cast when assigning it as the view's delegate fails. Make `Renderer` explicitly conform to the protocol, and remove the conditional cast as shown above.

```
class Renderer: NSObject, MTKViewDelegate
```

Comment: This works, thank you. But, why do I have to keep the renderer? Isn't it that it is inside the delegate of the view?

Comment: It sounds like you may not understand the distinction between strong and weak references. You can [read more here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html).

Answer (score 0):

Well, it could be anything. But, the first thing I would check is that your alpha setting for that red color should have alpha = 1.0 and not alpha = 0.0.

Comment: Thank you, it is a problem though.